# I lost access to a topic I wrote and submitted for review but discarded accidently

Tags: support, documentation

I completed a topic "How to add Multiple SSH keys on a client" to be part of "Documentation (beta)". I wrote it, selected it for review but then tried to edit something later and accidentally selected "Discard draft".

Now, I can't find the document :/ I spent like 1 hour writing it. It was in "ssh" category.